# GWT: Pros and Cons of using EventBus with Cells

Tags: events, gwt

We are injecting our app-wide eventBus to our Cells (classes extending AbstractCell).
We reckon it is more confortable to fire events which will be handled by other presenters instead of using the ValueUpdater.
Any pros / cons ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the `ValueUpdater`s to serve a very specific purpose - updating values that the cells have changed. This is the basic contract established by most of the editable cells, and the button/action cells that overload it annoy me.

That said, using the global event bus might be going too far. A few intermediate options:

- EventBus instance per column/cell (same thing, really), so that the events can be very local if need be, or can be listened to and re-broadcast at a higher level. One of the main benefits of this approach is that your cells might be reusable, exposing their api as events for different use cases to consume
- Local event bus for just that view/presenter, again elevating app-wide events to the global presenter when necessary. Less reusable than the first option, but often times code doesn't need to be reusable.

I don't like my global event bus to get too spammy, in part to make debugging easier, and in part to not worry too much if a given view/presenter is inefficient in its use of events, as that wont affect the rest of the app. Gives the chance to build first, and optimize later.